# Setting up a samba share between windows xp and ubuntu 11 in a vm player

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-xp, samba

I am trying to mount a shared folder from windows xp to my ubuntu vm.  It is running in vm player.

I installed samba with `sudo apt-get smbclient smbfs`

Next, I run `smbclient -L computer_name_here` and get the error NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE.  What am I doing wrong?  How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that I can think of is to check the network type, in settings. I think it works properly with a nat'ed interface, however if you want to be sure, you can try a host only network. Also, look into the -U option for smbclient, and specify a suername:

```
smbclient -L computer_name -U user_name
```